# Mysql 8 enable plugin X

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, mysql-x-devapi

few days ago I created mysql cluster on digitalocean (by default it starts on port 25060).
When I installed MySQL Connector/Node.js and tried to establish connection with default port and it went on error saying :

"Error: The server connection is not using the X Protocol. Make sure you , are connecting to the correct port and using a MySQL 5.7.12 (or higher) server intance."

After some research I've learned that to use X devApi of mysql I should connect on port 33060 (that my cluster does not use at all), but unfortunately mysqlx plugin is disabled on my cluster, which confuses me a lot cause i know mysql8 enables it by default

[image: proof that mysqlx is disabled]

my question is , is there any way i can activate mysqlx plugin ?

Answer (score 0):

In theory, you can enable/install and disable/uninstall the X Plugin, provided the server has access to the library.

As described [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/document-store-setting-up.html):

```
-- unix systems
INSTALL PLUGIN mysqlx SONAME 'mysqlx.so';
-- windows systems
INSTALL PLUGIN mysqlx SONAME 'mysqlx.dll';
```

In practice, though, maybe digital Ocean is running an older version of MySQL (which does not seem to be the case), does not give you access to the library, or access to port 33060 or whatever port you might able to bind the X Plugin to. So, you might be out of luck, but I guess you can try.

Disclaimer: I'm the lead developer of the MySQL X DevAPI Connector for Node.js