# MySQL Azure Database | Enable mysqlx plugin

Tags: mysql, azure, plugins, azure-mysql-database

I am trying to enable the mysqlx plugin in my company's MySQL Azure database, so that I can use the [JSON import utility in MySQL Shell](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-shell/8.0/en/mysql-shell-utilities-json.html).

The server version is 8.0, for which mysqlx is enabled by default. However, executing `SHOW PLUGINS` reveals that mysqlx is `DISABLED`:

[*mysqlx is disabled for the server*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/avYAx.png)

[MySQL documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/mysql-8.0-en/x-plugin-options-system-variables.html#:%7E:text=In%20MySQL%208.0%2C%20X%20Plugin%20is%20enabled%20by,on%20which%20X%20Plugin%20listens%20for%20TCP%2FIP%20connections.) states that this plugin can be enabled by executing `-- mysqlx=ON` in the MySQL shell, but for me this just returns the `SyntaxError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment`.

I also consulted [this Stack Overflow page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61666495/mysql-8-enable-plugin-x), but the proposed solution requires installing a file, which I do not have the permission to do, even though  I am using the server admin account: `Error Code: 1044. Access denied for user 'user'@'%' to database 'mysql'`.

Any suggestions for how to activate this plugin would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not supported in Azure DB for MySQL today, I would recommend to upvote this item for product team to prioritize exposing this plugin

https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/53d0aec7-482c-ed11-a81b-6045bd853c94